# What is .withDOM('frtip')?

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

Hey can anyone please tell me what is this 'frtip' inside the .DOM()  and is there any documentation to understand this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It controls where and which table control elements you will have.

From the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom):

```
l - length changing input control
f - filtering input
t - The table!
i - Table information summary
p - pagination control
r - processing display element
```